# NSMutableArray object add to string

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray with 3 data or more. I need String with this data like: "data1,data2,data3".

My code:

```
for(int x=0; x<data.count;x++)
    {  
      NSString *string = [data objectAtIndex:x]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data1", @"data2", @"data3", nil];
NSMutableString *finalString = [[NSMutableString alloc]  init];

for (int x = 0; x < data.count; x++)
{
    NSString *string = [data objectAtIndex:x];
    [finalString appendFormat:x == data.count-1 ? @"%@" : @"%@,", string];
}

NSLog(@"finalString: %@", finalString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the other solutions... and this solution popped into my mind; I don't see why this solution would not be not good enough, because it looks more sophisticated and more elegant:

```
NSArray *_myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item-1", @"item-2", @"item-3", nil];
NSString *_myString = [_myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

the final result would be:

```
item-1, item-2, item-3
```

---

*NOTE: of course, the input array can be `NSMutableArray` as well, it would not affect the final output.*

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that you want to join all datas into one string?

If I am right, here are the codes:

```
NSMutableString *dataStr = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        [dataStr appendString:[data objectAtIndex:i]];
    } else {
        [dataStr appendFormat:@",%@", [data objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: @WildWorld The codes are OK only if your datas are NSString type. What is the contents of your data array?

Comment: there is a much better solution than this odd one.